# rake aborted! Could not find a JavaScript runtime

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a beginner in Ruby and I have had some trouble starting

I created a demo project:

```
C:\Sites>rails new demo
      create
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      ...
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using mail (2.5.4)
Installing actionmailer (4.0.2)
...
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed
```

Next, selected the folder:

```
C:\Sites>cd demo
```

I maked rake... and plop!

```
C:\Sites\demo>rake about
rake aborted!
Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
C:/Sites/demo/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Sites/demo/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I tried run the server... but not works

```
C:\Sites\gui>rails server
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/run
times.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://gi
thub.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUn
available)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.2/l
ib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.2/l
ib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

Help me, pls.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The reason is pretty self explanatory and says that a JS runtime was not available. You can explicitly add that dependency by adding `rubyracer` gem to your rails application, and that should include the JS runtime, for you.

So, add `gem 'therubyracer'` to your `Gemfile`, and then, run `bundle` command, again. Then, you can run your `rake` or `rails` commands, as desired :)

If that does not solve your problem, install `node.js` on your system, and that should solve your problem, for sure. You can use:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs # on ubuntu
brew install node # on mac-osx, if you have `homebrew` installed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a javascript runtime.

Install node.js from here http://nodejs.org/. Make sure that the executable added to PATH.